Причина ошибок Request textDocument/... в Visual Studio Code
В VS Code при переключении из ограниченного режима просмотра кода в доверенный внизу справа начинают вылазить ошибки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что их вызывает и как от них избавиться?
VS Code поставил всего пару дней назад. Нужна она мне просто как блокнот с intellisense, чтобы не нужно было каждый раз создавать целый проект только ради того, чтобы выписать мысли из головы и как следует их обдумать. Так что прокачивать её с помощью плагинов до уровня близкого к IDE я не собираюсь - обычная VS для этого вполне устраивает. Нужен только редактор без сохранения, из которого можно при случае что-то копипастнуть в VS.
Если также порекомендуете бесплатные аналоги, удовлетворяющие запросу, буду очень признателен. Заранее спасибо!

